# Convert site from SP-Initiated SSO Redirect POST to IdP-Initiated SSO POST

Tags: php, single-sign-on, saml

Up until now, I have been using simplesamlphp for SP-Initiated SSO Redirect for our third party applications.  But our latest client does IdP-Initiated SSO instead.

I was given this page [to explain how it works](http://saml.xml.org/wiki/idp-initiated-single-sign-on-post-binding), and from a high-level perspective it completely makes sense. But I cannot find documentation on simplesamlphp's site on how to go about this change except changelog pages.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from someone. The title of the page isn't as obvious as I thought, which would explain my lack of knowing what to search for.

http://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-sp